Compilation failing on MacOS with weird errors when _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined
With the follow compiler flags:
-std=c11 -Werror -Wpedantic

Oracle Solaris 14.6 requires _POSIX_C_SOURCE/_XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined for the declaration of clock_gettime(), a function that's used by the this testing library I am including in the translation unit below.
The code compiles fine after defining it, but fails when compiled under Apple MacOS with these errors:
cc -std=c11 -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wno-unused-function -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeprecated -DDEBUG    tests.c   -o tests
In file included from tests.c:19:
In file included from ./acutest.h:377:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/sysctl.h:83:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/ucred.h:101:2: error: unknown type name 'u_int'
        u_int   cr_version;             /* structure layout version */
        ^
In file included from tests.c:19:
In file included from ./acutest.h:377:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/sysctl.h:85:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:116:2: error: unknown type name 'u_int'
        u_int   p_estcpu;        /* Time averaged value of p_cpticks. */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:121:2: error: unknown type name 'u_int'
        u_int   p_swtime;        /* Time swapped in or out. */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:122:2: error: unknown type name 'u_int'
        u_int   p_slptime;       /* Time since last blocked. */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:136:2: error: unknown type name 'u_char'; did you mean 'char'?
        u_char  p_priority;     /* Process priority. */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:137:2: error: unknown type name 'u_char'; did you mean 'char'?
        u_char  p_usrpri;       /* User-priority based on p_cpu and p_nice. */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:142:2: error: unknown type name 'u_short'; did you mean 'short'?
        u_short p_xstat;        /* Exit status for wait; also stop signal. */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h:143:2: error: unknown type name 'u_short'; did you mean 'short'?
        u_short p_acflag;       /* Accounting flags. */
        ^
8 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [tests] Error 1
make: *** [test] Error 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

What are these unknown types, and why do these errors disappear if I remove the macros?
Currently, I am avoiding these by only defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE/_XOPEN_SOURCE for Solaris:
#if defined(__sun) && defined(__SVR4)
    #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L
    #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#endif

And here's the translation unit:
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
    #define HAVE_STDALIGN_H
    #include <stdalign.h>
#endif

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include "acutest.h"

#include "arena.c"

/* *INDENT-OFF* */
/* In C2X/C23 or later, nullptr is a keyword. */
/* Patch up C18 (__STDC_VERSION__ == 201710L) and earlier versions.  */
#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || __STDC_VERSION__ <= 201710L
    #define nullptr ((void *)0)
#endif
/* *INDENT-ON* */

static inline bool is_aligned(const void *ptr, size_t byte_count)
{
    return (uintptr_t) ptr % byte_count == 0;
}

static void test_arena_new(void)
{
    TEST_CHECK(arena_new(stderr, 0) == nullptr);

    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_CHECK(arena);
    arena_destroy(arena);

    uint8_t *const backing_storage1 = malloc(100 * (size_t) 1024);

    TEST_ASSERT(backing_storage1);

    Arena *const heap_arena = arena_new(backing_storage1, 100 * (size_t) 1024);

    TEST_CHECK(heap_arena);
    arena_destroy(heap_arena);
    free(backing_storage1);

#ifdef HAVE_STDALIGN_H
    static uint8_t alignas (max_align_t) backing_storage2[BUFSIZ];
    Arena *const static_arena =
        arena_new(backing_storage2, sizeof backing_storage2);
    TEST_CHECK(static_arena);
    arena_destroy(static_arena);

    uint8_t alignas (max_align_t) backing_storage3[BUFSIZ];
    Arena *const thread_local_arena =
        arena_new(backing_storage3, sizeof backing_storage3);
    TEST_CHECK(thread_local_arena);
    arena_destroy(thread_local_arena);
#endif
}

static void test_arena_destroy(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_reset(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);
    arena_reset(arena);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arena->count; ++i) {
        TEST_CHECK(arena->pools[i]->offset == 0);
    }

    TEST_CHECK(arena->current == 1);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_alloc(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);

    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 112) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 0, 1) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 0) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 2, 5) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 3, 5) == nullptr);

    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 95));
    uint8_t *const curr_pool = arena->pools[0]->buf;

    TEST_CHECK(curr_pool[96] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[97] == 0xA5
        && curr_pool[98] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[99] == 0xA5);

    arena_reset(arena);

#ifdef HAVE_STDALIGN_H
    const int *const a = arena_alloc(arena, alignof (int), 5 * sizeof *a);
    const double *const b = arena_alloc(arena, alignof (double), 2 * sizeof *b);
    const char *const c = arena_alloc(arena, 1, 10);
    const short *const d = arena_alloc(arena, alignof (short), 5 * sizeof *d);

    TEST_CHECK(a && is_aligned(a, alignof (int)));
    TEST_CHECK(b && is_aligned(b, alignof (double)));
    TEST_CHECK(c && is_aligned(c, 1));
    TEST_CHECK(d && is_aligned(d, alignof (short)));
#endif
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_resize(void)
{
    Arena *arena = arena_new(nullptr, 1000);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);

    TEST_CHECK(arena_resize(arena, stderr, 0) == nullptr);

    arena = arena_resize(arena, nullptr, 10000);
    TEST_CHECK(arena);
    TEST_CHECK(arena->current == 2 && arena->count == 2);

    const char *c = arena_alloc(arena, 1, 10000);

    TEST_ASSERT(c);

    arena_reset(arena);
    TEST_CHECK(arena->current == 1 && arena->count == 2);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_allocarray(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);

#ifdef HAVE_STDALIGN_H
    const int *const nums =
        arena_allocarray(arena, alignof (int), 10, sizeof *nums);
    TEST_CHECK(nums);
#endif

    TEST_CHECK(arena_allocarray(arena, 0, 10, 20) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_allocarray(arena, 10, 0, 20) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_allocarray(arena, 10, 20, 0) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_allocarray(arena, 2, 10, SIZE_MAX) == nullptr);

    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_realloc(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 10));
    TEST_CHECK(arena->pools[0]->offset == 10 && arena->last_alloc_size == 10);

    /* Test expansion. */
    TEST_CHECK(arena_realloc(arena, 20));
    TEST_CHECK(arena->pools[0]->offset == 20 && arena->last_alloc_size == 20);

    /* Test shrinking. */
    TEST_CHECK(arena_realloc(arena, 15));
    TEST_CHECK(arena->pools[0]->offset == 15 && arena->last_alloc_size == 15);

    /* Test deletion. */
    TEST_CHECK(arena_realloc(arena, 0));
    TEST_CHECK(arena->pools[0]->offset == 0 && arena->last_alloc_size == 0);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_pool_capacity(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);
    TEST_ASSERT(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 40));
    TEST_CHECK(arena_pool_capacity(arena) == 60);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 49));
    TEST_CHECK(arena_pool_capacity(arena) == 11);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 11));
    TEST_CHECK(arena_pool_capacity(arena) == 0);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_allocated_bytes(void)
{
    Arena *arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);
    arena = arena_resize(arena, nullptr, 10002);
    TEST_ASSERT(arena);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_allocated_bytes(arena) == 10102);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

static void test_arena_allocated_bytes_including_metadata(void)
{
    Arena *arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);
    arena = arena_resize(arena, nullptr, 10002);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_allocated_bytes_including_metadata(arena) == 10102
        + offsetof(Arena, pools)
        + sizeof arena->pools[0] * arena->capacity);
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

/* *INDENT-OFF* */
TEST_LIST = {
    { "arena_new", test_arena_new },
    { "arena_destroy", test_arena_destroy },
    { "arena_reset", test_arena_reset },
    { "arena_alloc", test_arena_alloc },
    { "arena_resize", test_arena_resize },
    { "arena_allocarray", test_arena_allocarray },
    { "arena_realloc", test_arena_realloc },
    { "arena_pool_capacity", test_arena_pool_capacity},
    { "arena_allocated_bytes", test_arena_allocated_bytes },
    { "arena_allocated_bytes_including_metadata", test_arena_allocated_bytes_including_metadata },
    { nullptr, nullptr }
};
/* *INDENT-ON* */


Note: I do not have access to the MacOS system.

You most likely want to move those defines to before you include any standard library files so they have an effect. Even better would be to define them on the compile command line.

@Retired Ninja Same results as before: https://github.com/Melkor-1/arena/actions/runs/8905976121/job/24457404089#step:3:35 Build failed.

This is trivially reproduced with a source file containing only #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L and #include <sys/sysctl.h>. As a workaround, you might try #include <sys/types.h> before any other #include or #define directives in the file. That is not a correction, just a kludge for the moment.

Including <sys/types.h> in tests.c before any other include or define directive fixes all errors for missing types. As @Eric says in the comments, that is not a correction, just a kludge for the moment.
